# Tailwindcss is working using npm run dev, but not in the static html out folder generated using npm run build, the export files are not working fine

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, next.js13

I am not getting any error also,only Getting this while using netlify-> Failed during stage "building site": Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2.

I was expecting working static html pages, i cannot also deploy my site to a server like vercel or netlify,the console is also free of any errors,